# Hide all the rows after a specific row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC application with C#, .NET Framework 4.7 and jQuery 3.1.1.

I have a view with a table:

```
<table id="myTable">
<tbody>
   <tr> ... </tr>
   <tr> ... </tr>
   <tr> ... </tr>
   <tr id="row_x"> ... </tr>
   <tr> ... </tr>
   <tr> ... </tr>
   <tr> ... </tr>
   ...
```

I want to hide all the rows under the row `<tr id="row_x"> ... </tr>` but I don't know how to access those rows. Do I need to set an id to all of them?

I've thought to surround them with a `<div>` but I don't think it is a good idea or possible.

Comment: You want to hide all the `td`, so you can use `$("#row_x td").hide()` And if you want to hide everything after this `tr`, you should use `$("#row_x").nextAll().hide()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the jQuery method [`nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

```js
$("#row_x").nextAll().hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row_x">
      <td>Row 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#row_x").nextAll('tr').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row_x">
      <td>Row 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Just try like this

```
 $('#row_x').nextAll('tr').hide();
```

Comment: This looks exactly like my answer

Comment: Yes that is the only solution with some modification :)

Comment: The `tr` selector isn't necessary since the only siblings are rows anyway.